# Spring Boot code, workflow is -> upload file - then tamper with file - download the file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am doing the following tutorial at spring.io (https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) and this is my first spring-boot application, I am a java-developer. I am using the Maven-approach and deploying it as a stand-alone jar (not relevant to the use-cases really).

The question about the code has to do with structuring and boils down to the question  "where should I put in my 'business-logic'?". The logic that I would like to apply concerns the following 2 use-cases.

1. I want to transform 2 columns in the uploaded csv-file (or excel-file) and let the user download the 'transformed'-file.
2. If the user uploads an image file, I want to check if there are any EXIF-Tags (such as coordinates ++ ) in the image - and if there is, I would like to store that information in a database.

Or should I take a broader look at Spring MVC or similar technologies when it comes to my use-cases ?

best, Ingo

Right now I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and  using java 1.8, maven 3.0.5 and Netbeans 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> "where should I put in my 'business-logic'?"

You basically want your Controller to handle your requests only and let another class handle the logic, which is a Service in Spring terms.

You would have a file `MyService.java` similar to this:

```
@Service
class MyService {

    public MyData handleCSV(<your parameters>) {
        return ...
    }

}
```

In your Controller you can inject your service and simply use it:

```
@Controller
class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService; 

}
```

That's it. Anywhere in this controller, you can call the myService instance.

Comment: Thank you Zwepp. If you look at the example at spring.io above you can see the control-class (FileUploadController).
That class handles all the RESTful-services; Methods like 'handleFileUpload' and  'serveFile' (with respective annotations) are here.
 So what I would like to do, is to save the original-file (current functionality), but where should I call  a method such as  
'public File transform(File file){... return transformedFile }'? Should I put that in the 'serveFile' and transform the file before I do the return statement ? - you could easily get the code running(github) -Ingo